# DataContractJsonSerializer issue if property return type interface with nested property return type

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

Need to serialize into JSON string and Deserialize the JSON string into object.

here my class flow.

```
[DataContract]
public class BatchItem_NF : INF
{
    [DataMember]
    public IDebtor Debtor { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IList<IDebtor> AllDebtors
    {
        get
        {
            return _debtors;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Debtor : IDebtor
{
    [DataMember]
    public IAddress Address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Address : IAddress
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Here what i am  trying to serialize but not working

```
private string BatchItem_NFSerialization(INF Alldebtors)
{
    Type t = Alldebtors.GetType();
    extraTypes1 = t.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsInterface)
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(Alldebtors, null).GetType())
        .ToArray();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(t, extraTypes1);
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, ((BatchItem_NF)Alldebtors));

        retVal = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

it is throwing below error:
Type 'Address' with data contract name 'Address:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer

someone can help

Comment: Don't declare it as `IAddress`, just declare it as `Address`. Why do you think you need an interface on a DTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get known types only for the first level of properties. In your code you get only `Debtor` type but you should also process this property to get `Address` type for example through recursion.

```
private static string BatchItem_NFSerialization(INF Alldebtors)
{
    Type t = Alldebtors.GetType();
    var extraTypes1 = GetKnownTypes(Alldebtors);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(t, extraTypes1);
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, ((BatchItem_NF)Alldebtors));

        var retVal = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        return retVal;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(object property)
{
    Type t = property.GetType();

    var extraValues = t.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsInterface && !p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        .Select(p => p.GetValue(property, null))
        .ToArray();

    var extraTypes = extraValues.SelectMany(GetKnownTypes).ToArray();

    return extraValues.Select(v => v.GetType()).Concat(extraTypes).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. great Help.. but small issue resulting  an extra ""__type":"Debtor:" and "__type":"Address"  in JSON strng. any idea to block this in result string...

Comment: @greensoil no because it is required in order to know what class which implements `IAddress` is required. To get rid of this just declare the property as `Address` not `IAddress`.

Comment: How to Deserialize the above generated string "JSON"  into object?

Comment: I highly recommend using specialized library for JSON serialization/deserialization - [Newtonsoft Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).